# Arduino Error with Casting from string to float

Tags: string, arduino

In following code, I'm Trying to cast String value to float, but i get Following error."class String has no named toFloat".Error in following line  " yaw = s.substring(5,s.indexOf(",",i)).toFloat();".

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial softSerial(2, 3);
String buff;



void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
softSerial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
             if(softSerial.available()){
             buff = "";
            while(softSerial.available()){
            char in = (char)softSerial.read();
                  buff += in;
           }
             Serial.println(buff);
             parseData(buff);
 }

 if(Serial.available()){
                         while(Serial.available()){
                         softSerial.write(Serial.read());
                                                  }
                       }
                       }

                       void parseData(String s){

                        union byte2float{
                        byte bval[4];
                        float fval;
                             }
                          b2f;

                       float yaw;
               float pitch;
            float roll;
           int i=0;
            String temp;
       //Check if ASCII or Binary (usually, binary output doesn't start with #)
        if(s.substring(0,1)=="#"){
         if(s.substring(1,4)=="YPR"){
        Serial.println("Output is Text");
         Serial.println(s.substring(5,s.indexOf(",",i)));
         yaw = s.substring(5,s.indexOf(",",i)).toFloat();

         i = 1 + s.indexOf(",",i) ;
         Serial.println(s.substring(i,s.indexOf(",",i)));
         pitch = s.substring(i,s.indexOf(",",i)).toFloat();

         i = 1 + s.indexOf(",",i);
         Serial.println(s.substring(i,s.indexOf(",",i)));
          roll = s.substring(i,s.indexOf(",",i)).toFloat();


          }
          }
          else{
             // 1234 5678 9101112
            Serial.println("Output is Binary: ");
                byte b[13];
             s.getBytes(b,13);
                  Serial.println("[#]\t[A]\t[B]\t[Ah]\t[Bh]");
                  for(int x=0;x<12;x++){
                  Serial.print("[");
                  Serial.print(x,DEC);
                  Serial.print("]\t");
                  Serial.print(s[x]);
                  Serial.print("\t");
                  Serial.print((char)b[x]);
                  Serial.print("\t");
                  Serial.print((byte)s[x],HEX);
                  Serial.print("\t");
                  Serial.println((byte)b[x],HEX);
                    }
                   b2f.bval[0] = b[0];
              b2f.bval[1] = b[1];
                    b2f.bval[2] = b[2];
                     b2f.bval[3] = b[3];
                  yaw = b2f.fval;    
                b2f.bval[0] = b[4];
                  b2f.bval[1] = b[5];
                 b2f.bval[2] = b[6];
                 b2f.bval[3] = b[7];
               pitch = b2f.fval;    
             b2f.bval[0] = b[8];
           b2f.bval[1] = b[9];
            b2f.bval[2] = b[10];
              b2f.bval[3] = b[11];
              roll = b2f.fval;    
            }
            Serial.print("Yaw: ");
           Serial.println(yaw);
        Serial.print("Pitch: ");
           Serial.println(pitch);
          Serial.print("Roll: ");
           Serial.println(roll);
              }
```

Comment: What board/core are you using?

Comment: code cannot pass debug  process on pc

Comment: That is not what I asked. The main reason asking this is some cores do not have up to date code, like the Galileo or old IDE versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use for example

```
float(s.substring(5,s.indexOf(",",i)))
```

instead of

```
s.substring(5,s.indexOf(",",i)).toFloat()
```

The error message says, you were using the `toFloat()` method of a string, which does not exists. Instead, pass the string into the global function `float(string)`.

Comment: gives casting error, anyway i found that toFloat() is not available in old versions of arduino thanks !